# Model Building Process Without Feature Names/Domain Knowledge

Tags: feature-selection, model-selection

I am working with a dataset of $\approx 10^7$ samples and $\approx 120$ features. All samples have a binary classification $0 - 1$. I am attempting to build a model that minimizes out-of-sample error with not much importance placed on inference. (More of a machine learning than classic statistics framework I guess). Unfortunately, none of the features are named. To prevent against overfitting, I'm motivated to perform some sort of feature selection. When solely focused on accuracy, is there a good approach? The only thing that comes to mind is sequential feature selection using a greedy algorithm, and finding when validation accuracy begins to decrease. Any other thoughts?

Furthermore, what is the correct model iteration process? Do I compare models like LDA/QDA vs decision trees, then perform feature selection once I've selected a model? Finally, where would something like hyperparameter tuning fit into this process?

Comment: Are you sure none of features are leaking?  Without names or domain knowledge it can be a risk that some leaked information is in your data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure I completely understand your setup, especially regards the feature names. In all of your datasets features are traceable? That is, the 3rd column, for example, will mean the same?

**Regarding the Type of Feature Selection Method to use**
There is no one best option that will always win against others. Some relay on statistical assumptions and information theory (CMIM, for example), other on distance (SURF and its variants). Another important distinction would be the paradigm by which you do the feature selection. One might require you to run a model of some sort (*embedded methods*), other will look at the features themselves regardless of a model (*filter methods*) and also you have the method you were referring to, of forward/backward elimination. Each of the paradigm might be preferable under some circumstances. For example, iteratively running models might be very computationally expensive and time demanding, and it also may prone to overfit. Also, if your final model is `XGBoost`, for example, it would make no sense to use a `logistic regression` for the feature selection stage.

**How to Evaluate Your Feature Selection Method**
Basically, as you assess yourself on any choice of hyper-parameter combination, on the validation set. You can treat the FS stage as another hyper-parameter to choose, where you want to find the combination that maximizes your performance on the validation set.
The only caveat, is again, computation power and time constraint. For a set of features, maybe the best hyperparameters combination would be `x` while for another set of features combination `z` would be the best, therefore it is tempting to search for a best combination of hyperparameters under every combination of features, but as you might see already, it is impractical. Therefore, what is being done in most of the companies I am familiar with, is (1) look for a best feature combination; then (2) hyperparameter tuning.
For more information about feature selection, I kindly point you to the following introduction [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/feature-selection-for-the-lazy-data-scientist-c31ba9b4ee66).

**When focusing on Accuracy Alone**
This a somewhat unrelated question. Should you be looking at accuracy alone? Is your data balanced? Does the threshold matter? Do you have the same utility from true positive and true negative? I feel like it is a bit beyond the scope of the feature selection problem, as you want to choose features that maximize *your* KPI of choice.

Comment: Yes, the columns are traceable. In response to your last point, I realized that accuracy is not the end all by all: true positives incur a 'reward' while false positives incur a 'penalty' so the total utility is the sum of true positives minus false positives. That is my KPI. Thus, the simplest sort of feature selection (to me) seems to be an iterative model using KPI. While using information theory-based methods sounds awesome, I'm not sure how useful they'd be for my specific KPI.